# IFrame Back button

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I searched a lot to get rid of this problem on the internet but could not find a specific solution despite the problem being discussed in details previously.

The query is simple. My javascript dynamically adds an Iframe to the web page (which displays a feedback form). The problem is that, "after answering", now when the user clicks the back-button of the browser the iframe instead of the browser window is affected i.e. the questionnaire is displayed again. I want the browser back button to behave normally.

This behavior is really annoying and I am having real trouble fixing this.

I am using firefox.

Looking forward to the replies. Please inform me if I should give more details.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form has a submit button, which posts the page to the server. The back button will always send the user back to the form regardless of whether you use a iframe or not. The ideal way is to notify the user of a completed action, in this case thank the user for the feedback (using an alert box) and redirect the user to the home page or provide a button in the page saying "Back to Home".

Comment: agree with this, anything that changes this behavior of back would rather confuse the user.

Comment: I will provide more context: the script is part of an extension which works on a public domain web site. I already have a "Back to previous page" link but I still want the back button to function as I have written in my post. I somehow want to decouple or remove the Iframe history from the browser history but I am not sure if I can do that?

Comment: The only way you can do that is to use AJAX to post your form values to the server. This way you avoid a post back and the back button will work just take you to the previous page. But this involves a fair amount of javascript coding to post data to the server and then hide the form fields once you get a valid response. Using jQuery for Ajax will make it a bit easier for you. But I doubt whether you can remove browser history.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox and IE indeed act like you mentioned, but Chrome do not, and I'd guess other WebKit browsers would do the same.
In Chrome, clicking the Back button will land you where you want to go (the previous URL of the parent frame). i.e. Chrome to not add iframe URL changes in the back button history.

Sadly, I've found no way to force IE and FF to replicate this, so I used the AJAX post approach suggested above by Arun.

Here's my iframe source, which use jQuery to post the form, and replace the whole page with the result of that POST:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="postForm(this);return false">
  ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function postForm(form) {
    $.post(form.action, $(form).serialize(), postCompleted);
}
function postCompleted(data) {
    $('html').html(data);
}
</script>
```

This works in all browsers; clicking the Back button will send you back to the previous URL a seen by the end user, instead of the initial form loaded dynamically in the iframe.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem: I use a dynamically created iframe to show a "popup" on my page, whose SRC points to another page that has got a form and a submit button. After submitting that page, a JS callback is used to hide the iframe. As you explained, this causes a new entry to be added to the history (on IE at least).

But I found out that **removing the iframe element from the DOM (instead of hiding it) results in the unwanted history entry being removed** (tested on IE9)! Which is what the user would expect in that situation.

You can observe this yourself on IE9:

1. Open the back button menu (right-click the back button): you only have one entry for the current page
2. Press submit in the iframe => the back button menu shows one extra entry for the iframe
3. Remove the iframe from the DOM => the back button menu no longer shows that entry

Comment: I ran in to this, and to refine this answer even more, ive found that if I do not specify the src of the iframe, until after the parent page is loaded, the weird back behavior does not occur.